# Installing/Cloning from Ubuntu Installed and Running on USB to HD

Tags: installation, usb, clone

I installed Ubuntu on to a USB and everything's running perfectly thus far. I can use it to boot into my desktop as well as laptops.

The question I have:-

I would like to use the Ubuntu on the USB to install/clone Ubuntu on to one or more laptops. I'd also like to have the same software as on my USB installed on the other systems. Any changes I have to make to individual system installations, I'll take care of later.

What's the best/easiest way of copying/cloning/installing a live system from a USB to the hard drive on multiple machines?

Answer (score 1):

**[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php)** is useful for that task related to "cloning"  (tested by me). The "Install" Procedure should be better if you run it from the installation disk and start from scratch.

With [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php), you can clone your USB's system into a hard disk drive, after which you will have a hard disk drive with the partitions as in your USB with extra unused disk space. (It would be cool if you provide us with the current partitioning sizes of your USB in order to give you a more comprehensive scenery).

You may wish to use all the hard disk drive capacity for the system. If so, you will simply need to start again from your USB, (the current one you use for booting or a live CD), then use **[gParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)**, erase your current swap file system in order to preserve your boot partition in one piece, and write a new swap at the very end of the partitions.

The procedure itself will delay a while depending on your hard disk drive capacity but it is easy indeed.

This procedure is how I cloned my 4GB USB system into a 8GB SD Card and some other cases with hard disk drive.

If you need further details please provide a screenshot of your current partitions in gparted, let us know how much memory does your computer have and the size of the hard disk drive where you wish to clone your system.

Cloning your system will preserve all your software, documents, configurations, etc.

Good luck!