# How to create bootable usb from pre-installed Ubuntu?

Tags: live-usb, iso

I am a new Ubuntu user. Whoever helped me assumes that I've actively downloaded Ubuntu and so have an ISO. But I got Ubuntu pre-installed, and want to create a bootable USB backup.

No idea what to point the Startup Disk Creator to. (This seems to be a good thing to have, maybe as a link for more info, on the How To Do It guides.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** Creating a bootable USB without using the downloaded ISO but the pre-installed Ubuntu is a little complicated for new users. If you want that, [see the answer below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184044/how-to-create-bootable-usb-from-pre-installed-ubuntu/184077?s=1%7C0.8146#184077). This answer gives two simpler alternatives.

## Make a *standard* bootable Ubuntu USB from within pre-installed Ubuntu (simple)

**Frist,** check the installed version of Ubuntu by opeining a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type `lsb_release -a`.

Note down the version number and OS Type (32bit or 64bit).

**Second,** download the ISO from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop, by selecting the appropriate version.

**Third,** insert an USB drive (4GB or greater for Ubuntu, 2GB or greater for Lubuntu, Xubuntu).

The **Startup Disk Creater** takes two inputs, the location of the ISO file and the location of the USB drive.

**Fourth,** point the **Startup Disk Creater** to the ISO and the USB drive.

See the help on [Create a usb stick on ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) for a simple set of instructions.

Also see a more [detailed instructions on USB stick creation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

## Remastersys does not exist anymore.

### The next section is obsolete.

#### Make a *custom* bootable backup Ubuntu USB from pre-installed Ubuntu (Complicated)

**First,** Add Remastersys source information to Software Center. Open Software Center and click on “Edit” and select “Software Sources.”

Select the “Other Software” tab at the top and you need to click the “Add” button, and copy and paste this:

```
deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu precise main
```

And then click “+Add Source”, then click "Close" and completely close out of Software Center.

Add the PGP key for the Remastersys repository, in Terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) copy the two lines below one line at a time and paste (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) in Terminal:

```
wget -O - http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/remastersys.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

**Second,** install Remastersys. Open Software Center and search for and install remastersys.

**Third,** run Remastersys. Click on "Backup" and wait a long time till it finishes creating the ISO file.

**Fourth,** create startup USB following instructions above.

More detailed information and some qualifications on how to do this is [here](http://debianhelp.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/how-to-install-and-use-remastersys-in-ubuntu-os/).
Hope this helps.

Comment: He said he wanted to create bootable USB from pre-installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you. It was counterintuitive to me that i should download the OS i already have, but it does seem easiest that way. I would suggest adding (a link to) this in help guides such as "create a usb stick on ubuntu". Best,

Comment: Add a disclaimer that this is not an answer to the actual question, and a link to the actual answer below, and I'll remove the downvote. ;P

Comment: @Cawas Thanks for drawing my attention to this issue. Done.

Comment: Remastersys is discontinued.

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks for the comment. I have updated the answer.

Comment: "Third, insert an USB drive (1GB or greater, 2GB or greater if you want to make it persistent)." The current `ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso` file is slightly bigger than 2 GB, so you should recommend minimum 4 GB size of the target drive except for the small Ubuntu family flavours (e.g. Lubuntu and Xubuntu), where 2 GB is enough.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for the catch. Ubuntu Live USB certainly has grown in size since 2012! I have edited the answer.

Comment: +1 and thanks for keeping the answer up to date :-)

Comment: @sudodus thanks again for pointing it out. Keeping old answers current and relevant is a tough job. :-)

Answer (score 14):

***I was writing this recipe when you hurried up to accept an answer, anyway this took a while to write, so here it is.***

One of your best chances to have such a "copy" of your current pre-installed operating system is to clone the installation itself, which will result in an exact operational copy of your hard disk drive's installed OS but in a bootable USB/SD/MicroSD card.

A relatively similar question was asked before, but the question was exactly the opposite of what you wish to achieve in this task. Anyway the same answer is useful for both your case and the previous question, you can reach it right here: [Installing/Cloning from Ubuntu Installed and Running on USB to HD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173459/installing-cloning-from-ubuntu-installed-and-running-on-usb-to-hd/173474#173474)

Additionally you may wish to take a look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/176110/9598 and this: https://askubuntu.com/a/106585/9598 or this: https://askubuntu.com/a/106585/9598. Note that they are basically the same answer but additional answers provided by different users in the same questions may give you a clue on how to do this task.

For your specific case, I suggest you to first check out how much disk space is your current pre-installed operating system using. This detail is important in order to gather the proper size's USB/SD/Micro SD Card so that the whole operating system can fit on that device. I am aware that Cloning can be done from smaller disks to a bigger one. But I haven't experienced yet with cloning from bigger to smaller disks so I can't suggest you about it. Which lead us to the next:

If the File system is bigger than the USB/SD/Micro SD Card, let's say: you have your current pre-installed OS In a 160 GB Hard disk drive, but it is only using 4 GB for the OS and other 20GB for documents, music, pictures and other data, you should decrease the partition itself in order to fit to the new device's size, let's analyze the scenery:

Having in mind a disk as of 160GB with 24 GB Total disk used (20 data, 4 OS) and wish to clone your OS into a 16GB USB/SD/Micro SD Card.

## **The recipe:**

**Ingredients**

1. [A Live CD/USB with Ubuntu and gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)
2. [A Live CD/USB with Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php)

**The directions**

1. You need to decrease the current 160GB partition to something like
   30 GB and leave the other 130GB unused.
2. Then let's create a container for spare space, the same size as your
   data, 30 GB so far. (from now on "spare partition")
3. Now let's create a bigger container for the data backup, the last
   100GB (from now on "backup partition")
4. Next, move your data (documents, pictures, music, etc.) into your
   backup partition in order to keep your data apart from the cloning
   process.
5. We need to match the new device's size and the partition size, so
   let's reduce again the system partition for a maximum of 16GB,
   leaving the remaining 14GB unused. You will then have a partitioning
   like this:

   |--SYSTEM-16gb--||--UNUSED-14gb--||---SPARE-30gb---||---------BACKUP-100gb---------|
6. This is the point where we start Clonezilla and run a cloning from
   device-device, to work directly from a disk-partition to
   disk-partition, in this case we are going to clone from "partition
   to disk"
7. After the cloning finishes and if you already checked that the USB
   properly boots, then we need to revert the process in order to leave
   your computer "as it was" before cloning your OS.
8. First we're going to expand the system partitions from its current
   size to the unused 14 gb in order to make it as of 30GB, size where
   you can put your backup data again in order to:
9. Remove the spare-30gb and the backup-100gb partitions in order to
   leave that space unused.
10. Expand the system partition to fill the 160gb of your hard disk
     drive.
11. And enjoy.

That seems to be a hard process but it is not indeed, it will take an hour or less, depending on your computer and the speed of your hard disk drive/optical drive (which will read the Clonezilla process).

For the operations related to resizing the partitions you can use gparted in a live CD, and you may wish to take a look at the answers to this question: [Why I'm seeing a lock besides the partition I'm trying to modify with gparted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted) in order to understand how to achieve that task, further information about gparted and Live Gparted images for both CD and USB can be reached right here: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

**REMEMBER:** *That you can't resize a partition that is currently in use (the system partition). So make sure you first run all the partitioning process before starting the cloning process.*

***Serve it cold and in companion with your favorite drink.***

Good luck!

***Some extra-explanations:***

1. **The spare-partition:** It is not required at all but I strongly suggest to make it in order to have extra space in order to keep
   your data apart from the cloning process or in case that you need
   extra space for resizing/moving your partitions.
2. **When cloning:** make sure you answer "yes" (just a "y" without quotation marks) when the Clonezilla asks you if you wish to clone
   the boot sector, otherwise your USB/SD/Micro SD Card won't boot.
3. **Remember:** It is strongly recommended to leave the OS alone, (with no user
   data) and to include the all the software that you wish to keep in
   the cloned device before cloning, nevertheless, after cloning you
   can run updates and/or install new software in the cloned device.
4. **You may wish** to use dd instead of Clonezilla, of which I won't give
   any explanation but you can find lots of answers over here.
5. **When serving the recipe:** make sure to include a glass with ice and
   Cuban rum for me.

Comment: This is a very nice recipe (Up-voted). However, it may be too complicated for "a new Ubuntu user" with pre-installed Ubuntu. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. Well, yes... I admit that in the first days, newcomers see this recipes and gets too scared but the recipe is easy indeed. Anyway the accepted answer provides a good choice and I placed this for 2 reasons: 1st: It took a while to write it, and 2nd: this newcomers will be professionals someday. :D Cheers!